# Exact distance geometry problem proof

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

How can one prove that the degree of each node in a distance graph must be *at least four* in order to obtain a unique solution to an exact distance geometry problem with sparse distance data?

The example in the Wiki article has *three* degrees for each node, which is *less than four*, but I am guessing the information derived in this case is not the same as what I am trying to prove; i.e. it is not a unique solution.

I am pretty confused, and any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

I interpret you question as follows. Suppose that we have a finite set $V$ of distinct points of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ and let $E$ be a set of edges over the set $V$ such that for each pair $x,y\in V$ connected by an edge the distance $d(x,y)$  is given. We wish to show that these distances  determine the set $V$ uniquely (in some sence), then each point $x\in V$ has degree at least $k=4$. For this purpose it is naturally to consider the case $n=k-1=3$, that is the usual space. Suppose that $x\in V$ and $\deg x=3$. Let the vertex $x$ is connected with the vertices $y_1,y_2,y_3$. Let $P$ be the plane spanned on the points $y_1,y_2,y_3$. Let $x’$ be a point symmetric to the point $x$ by the plane $L$. Then $d(x’,y_i)= d(x,y_i)$ for ever $i$, so if $x\ne x’$, the uniqueness of the point $x$ fails. The cases when $\deg x<3$ are considered similarly. So to assure the uniqueness of the set $V$ some degnerate cases should be excluded. 
For instance, maybe it suffices to impose the conditions "$|V|=5$" (to exclude the tetrahedron) and "no four points of the set $V$ are coplanar" (to assure that $x\ne x’$). When the dimension $n$ is different from 3, we should have the similar situation, but with $k=n+1$, so the exact distance geometry problem on the plane can have a unique solution when degree of each node in a distance graph is three.